# ExtJS Vertical Scroll Bar is not fitting for long json data

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, extjs

I have a Ext window in that having two items container and fieldset. For container and fieldset I am geting data in form of html from server.

If this data is big, scrollbar appears not navigate the text completly.

How can I configure a vertical scrollbar properly in this panel ?

My sample code is :

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title: 'DataSet',
    bodyPadding: 5,
    modal: true,
    height: 600,
    width: 900,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: {
        xtype: 'form',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'container',
            html: jsonData.R.ErrorMsg || ''
        }, {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            padding: '5 0 10 0',
            collapsible: true,
            title: 'Description',
            autoScroll: true,
            height: 580,
            width: 880,
            collapsed: true,
            overflowY: 'scroll',
            html: Ext.String.htmlEncode(jsonData.R.ErrorDesc) || ''
        }]
    }
})
```

Comment: Make a fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/ with the sample data.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are setting fixed width and height to the fieldset. If you want to have the scrollbar only when the content exceed the window size you first need to set the fieldset size as flex.

- Use `vbox` layout in form
- Replace fixed `height: 580` and `width: 880` with `flex: 1` in fieldset

Here is a working fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/30f9

Answer (score 0):

You can try this it works:

```js
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title: 'DataSet',
    bodyPadding: 5,
    modal: true,
    height: 600,
    width: 900,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: {
        xtype: 'form',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'container',
            html: jsonData.R.ErrorMsg || ''
        }, {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            padding: '5 0 10 0',
            collapsible: true,
            title: 'Description',
            height: 580,
            width: 880,
            collapsed: true,
            overflowY: 'scroll',
            html: Ext.String.htmlEncode(jsonData.R.ErrorDesc) || ''
        }]
    }
})
```

Comment: Yes I removed autoScroll: true, Vertical bar is coming but It not appearing for complete data. It getting Stuck at height 580 for container.

Answer (score 0):

Fieldset is **not** meant to be a form element(displaying html), It is meant to be a container for **grouping** **sets** of fields.

Creating a fieldset with child item **text area** or **text field**

```js
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title: 'DataSet',
    bodyPadding: 5,
    modal: true,
    height: 600,
    width: 900,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: {
        xtype: 'form',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'container',
            html: jsonData.R.ErrorMsg || ''
        }, {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            
            collapsed: true,
            overflowY: 'scroll',
            items: [
            {

                xtype: 'textfield',
                padding: '5 0 10 0',
                collapsible: true,
                title: 'Description',
                height: 580,
                width: 880,
                itemId: 'errorDesc',
                name: 'errorDesc',
                fieldLabel: 'Error Desc',
                value: Ext.String.htmlEncode(jsonData.R.ErrorDesc) || ''
            }
        }]
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The height of the parent container i.e "Ext.window.Window" is fixed at 600. You can try giving it at '100%' increasing its height.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
title: 'Simple Form with FieldSets',
labelWidth: 75, // label settings here cascade unless overridden
url: 'save-form.php',
frame: true,
bodyStyle: 'padding:5px 5px 0',
width: 550,
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
layout: 'column', // arrange fieldsets side by side
items: [{
    // Fieldset in Column 1 - collapsible via toggle button
    xtype:'fieldset',
    columnWidth: 0.5,
    title: 'Fieldset 1',
    collapsible: true,
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    defaults: {anchor: '100%'},
    layout: 'anchor',
    items :[{
        xtype:'container',
        html: Ext.String.htmlEncode("<input type=\"text\"> Hello </input>")
    }, {
        fieldLabel: 'Field 2',
        name: 'field2'
    }]
}]});
```

Here height is not specified and parent container's height will be based on the items it holds.